# Trace Oracle API execution

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I have made cursor which updates table values by using provided Oracle API. My question is how can I see which tables are affected? I would like to revert change in case that I need to so I would like to preserve those data first. Our Oracle database is version 12.1.0.2.

If trace can manage this how exactly can i do that? I tried with trace before but is pretty much unreadable to me :)

Thank you

Comment: When you say *"Oracle API"*, what exactly do you mean? Is this part of Oracle Apps?

Answer (score 0):

This is not answer, I cannot reply on comment. Yes this is API block code which I have used, my apologies for not being detailed previously:

```
declare
    --cursor to get all inactive users
cursor cur_inactive_user
is 
    select  fu.user_id,
        fd.responsibility_id,
        fd.responsibility_application_id,
        fd.security_group_id,
        fd.start_date,
        fu.end_date
    from fnd_user fu, fnd_user_resp_groups_direct fd
    where fu.user_id = fd.user_id
    and (fu.end_date < sysdate or fu.end_date is not null)
    and fd.end_date is null;
    --and fu.user_name='HFORD';
begin
    for rec_inactive_user in cur_inactive_user
    loop 
      -- checking if the responsibillity is assigned to the user 
      if (fnd_user_resp_groups_api.assignment_exists (
       rec_inactive_user.user_id,
       rec_inactive_user.responsibility_id,
       rec_inactive_user.responsibility_application_id,
        rec_inactive_user.security_group_id))
    then
        -- Call API to End date the responsibillity
        fnd_user_resp_groups_api.update_assignment (
        user_id                          => rec_inactive_user.user_id,
        responsibility_id                => rec_inactive_user.responsibility_id,
        responsibility_application_id    => rec_inactive_user.responsibility_application_id,
        security_group_id                => rec_inactive_user.security_group_id,
        start_date                       => rec_inactive_user.start_date,
        end_date                         => rec_inactive_user.end_date,
        description                      => null );
        --commit;
    end if;
    end loop;
end;
```